# Stream invalid; root page is outside of address range

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

When i run my application in IOS 9.2 i got following message can any one tell me why this message is appeared

> [/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreUI/CoreUI-371.4/Bom/Storage/BOMStorage.c:507]
>   stream invalid; root page is outside of address range

Comment: had the same error myself today. I'm using the CarbonKit menu, and when switching between portait and landscape, the menu 'moves' to a range outside the screen.